# Bandwith of a energy signal

Tags: bandwidth, signal-energy

I'm studying for my finals , and I'm struggling with finding bandwidths.

I have this energy spectral density : Ψ(f)=rect(f) , and I need to find the bandwith, 3 dB band and the band with 90 % power.

About the 90 % case, do I need to find the total energy and then ∫W0Ψ(f)=0.9×TotalEnergy?

If I had a power signal and wanted to find the 3 dB bandwidth, would I need to find the average power and then solve ∫W0Sx(f)=0.5×TotalPower ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: all these terms are well-googleable, and a drawing of the spectral density would instantly answer your questions – what really **is** your question?

Comment: You do realize that this is 3 entirely separate questions?  Just take them one by one.  You know the bandwidth; it was given in your knowns.  90% is 90% of that.  3 DB is where it crosses 3 DB; which in your case is at the band limit.  Of course, this presumes that you have a coherent signal; if the signal is real noise then the calculations differ.  Basically noise adds as the square root of bandwidth.